# Usage of StringBuffer or StringBuilder in EJB 3

Tags: java, ejb, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

In EJB 3 application (on WebSphere Application Server v7.0.0.21) I have one method which returns String. Inside the method I'm generating dynamic string using StringBuffer (tried with StringBuilder too and result is the same). The problem that is occuring every once in a while is that the content of the String gets all scrambled up. I'm struggling with this problem for quite some time now.

**EDIT**:

- added code for dao.properties, spring.xml, Dao.java, DaoBeanLocal.java, DaoBean.java and DaoSpringJdbc.java
- I'm using Java EE 5, JRE 1.6 and Spring JDBC 3.0.6

**Example 1**:

Users A and B call the method generateDocument at different time and both get the right result.

User A's result:

String1:1

String2:2

String3:3

String4:4

and user B's result:

String1:5

String2:6

String3:7

String4:8

**Example 2**:

Users A and B call the method generateDocument at the same time and both of them get the same scrambled result (part of the response is from user A and part of it is from user B):

String1:1

String2:2

<del>String3:7</del>

<del>String4:8</del>

**Sample code**

dao.properties

```
# jndi lookup string

jndi.datasource = jdbc/DS

# integers
select.integers = \
    SELECT \
        num1 \
    FROM \
        DBINTEGERS \
    WHERE \
        param1 = :param1 \
        AND param2 = :param2 \
    ORDER BY num1 \
    WITH UR

# custom object
select.custom.object = \
    SELECT \
        number1, number2, number3, number4 \
    FROM \
        DB_OBJECTS \
    WHERE \
        param1 = :param1 \
    ORDER BY number1 \
    WITH UR
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:dao.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="localOverride" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.WebSphereDataSourceAdapter">
        <property name="targetDataSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                <property name="jndiName" value="${jndi.datasource}" />
                <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="abstractDao" abstract="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="org.example.beans.dao.DaoSpringJdbc" parent="abstractDao">
        <property name="selectIntegers" value="${select.integers}" />
        <property name="selectCustomObject" value="${select.custom.object}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Dao.java

```
package org.example.beans.dao;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.example.beans.models.CustomObject;

public interface Dao {
    List<Integer> selectINTEGERS(String param1, String param2) throws SQLException;
    List<CustomObject> selectCustomObject(Integer param1) throws SQLException;
}
```

DaoBeanLocal.java

```
package org.example.beans.dao;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface DaoBeanLocal extends Dao {

}
```

DaoBean.java

```
package org.example.beans.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

@Stateless
public class DaoBean implements DaoBeanLocal {
    private Dao dao;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {

        try {
            this.dao = (Dao) getBeanFactory().getBean("dao", Dao.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //  log.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            throw new EJBException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    protected void destroy() {
        if (this.dao != null) {
            this.dao = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public List<Integer> selectINTEGERS(String param1, String param2) throws SQLException {
        return dao.selectINTEGERS(param1, param2);
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public List<CustomObject> selectCustomObject(Integer param1) throws SQLException {
        return dao.selectCustomObject(param1);
    }
}
```

DaoSpringJdbc.java

```
package org.example.beans.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport;

import org.example.beans.models.CustomObject;

public class DaoSpringJdbc extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements Dao {
    private String selectIntegers;
    private String selectCustomObject;

    @Override
    public List<Integer> selectINTEGERS(String param1, String param2) throws SQLException {
        final Map<String, Object> sqlParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        sqlParameters.put("param1", param1);
        sqlParameters.put("param2", param2);

        List<Integer> list = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(this.selectIntegers, sqlParameters, new RowMapper<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return (rs.getObject("num1") == null ? null : rs.getInt("num1"));
            }
        });

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CustomObject> selectCustomObject(Integer param1) throws SQLException {
        final Map<String, Object> sqlParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        sqlParameters.put("param1", param1);

        List<CustomObject> list = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(this.selectCustomObject, sqlParameters, new RowMapper<CustomObject>() {
            @Override
            public CustomObject mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                CustomObject o = new CustomObject();
                o.setNumber1(rs.getObject("number1") == null ? null : rs.getInt("number1"));
                o.setNumber2(rs.getObject("number2") == null ? null : rs.getInt("number2"));
                o.setNumber3(rs.getObject("number3") == null ? null : rs.getInt("number3"));
                o.setNumber4(rs.getObject("number4") == null ? null : rs.getInt("number4"));

                return o;
            }
        });

        return list;
    }

    public void setSelectIntegers(String selectIntegers) {
        this.selectIntegers = selectIntegers;
    }

    public void setSelectCustomObject(String selectCustomObject) {
        this.selectCustomObject = selectCustomObject;
    }
}
```

CustomObject.java

```
package org.example.beans.models;

public class CustomObject {
    private int number1;
    private int number2;
    private int number3;
    private int number4;

    public int getNumber1() {
        return this.number1;
    }

    public void setNumber1(int number1) {
        this.number1 = number1;
    }

    public int getNumber1() {
        return this.number1;
    }

    public void setNumber2(int number2) {
        this.number2 = number2;
    }

    public int getNumber2() {
        return this.number2;
    }

    public void setNumber3(int number3) {
        this.number3 = number3;
    }

    public int getNumber3() {
        return this.number3;
    }

    public void setNumber4(int number4) {
        this.number4 = number4;
    }

    public int getNumber4() {
        return this.number4;
    }
}
```

CustomException.java

```
package org.example.beans.exceptions;

import javax.ejb.ApplicationException;

@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class CustomException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomException() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomException(Throwable t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public CustomException(String detailMessage) {
        super(detailMessage);
    }

    public CustomException(String detailMessage, Throwable t) {
        super(detailMessage, t);
    }
}
```

Data.java

```
package org.example.beans.data;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.example.beans.models.CustomObject;
import org.example.beans.dao.DaoBeanLocal;
import org.example.beans.exceptions.CustomException;

public class Data {
    public void getContent(StringBuffer doc, DaoBeanLocal dao, Integer param1) throws CustomException {
        List<CustomObject> list = dao.selectCustomObject(param1);
        for (CustomObject obj : list) {
            doc.append("------------------");
            doc.append("String1: ").append(obj.getNumber1()).append("\n");
            doc.append("String2: ").append(obj.getNumber2()).append("\n");
            doc.append("String3: ").append(obj.getNumber3()).append("\n");
            doc.append("String4: ").append(obj.getNumber4()).append("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

DocumentBean.java

```
package org.example.beans;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

import org.example.beans.exceptions.CustomException;
import org.example.beans.data.Data;
import org.example.beans.dao.DaoBeanLocal;

@Stateless
public class DocumentBean implements DocumentRemote {
    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
    }

    @PreDestroy
    protected void destroy() {
    }

    // DAO local ejb
    @EJB
    private DaoBeanLocal dao;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public String generateDocument(String param1, String param2) throws CustomException {
        StringBuffer doc = new StringBuffer(10000);

        try {
            // some utility class
            Data data1 = new Data();
            Data data2 = new Data();
            Data data3 = new Data();
            Data data4 = new Data();

            // some data from database
            List<Integer> list = dao.selectIntegers(param1, param2);

            for (Integer param1 : list) {
                // a lot of usage of StringBuffer inside methods
                data1.getContent(doc, dao, param1);
                data2.getContent(doc, dao, param1);
                data3.getContent(doc, dao, param1);
                data4.getContent(doc, dao, param1);
            }
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            throw new CustomException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        String result = doc.toString();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I guess this is the problem with synchronization - threads. I thought that EJB context handles the synchronization and that each remote call is made in separate thread.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: As you said - each EJB is separate thread, so StringBuffer is not shared in any way. Add your dao to the listing, problem is probably there.

Comment: @Gas thank you for your input. Never thought that dao might be causing the problem. I've updated my question ...

Comment: Are you sure that output isn't for example like this: 
String1:5
String2:6
String1:1
String2:2
String3:7
String4:8
String3:3
String4:4
? Which would be perfectly legal as writing to the log is not synchronized.

Comment: @Gas GUI application (Java AWT) uses EJB client and the returned string is shown in the text area. Writing to the log is not the issue and is not used. What do you think about the DAO code? Why did you think DAO might be causing problems?

Comment: @Gas the output looks like a little is taken from user A response and little from user B response - seems like two different threads mixed together. And I can't duplicate the error.

Comment: Because StringBuffer is local method variable, so it is created per call and not shared in any way.  `dao = (Dao) getBeanFactory().getBean("dao", Dao.class);` is one place where same object could be shared among threads. And also DaoBeanLocal instance can be shared by DocumentBean instances. You should check if `NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport` is thread safe.